# What does MinimalPolynomial do?

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation, implementation-details

suppose $x^5-x-1=0$, $y^7-y-1=0$ and $z=x+y$.
I want to find a minimal polynomial expression of $z$, such that $p(z)=0$, and the code can be written like this:

```
MinimalPolynomial[Root[#^5 - # - 1 &, 1] + Root[#^7 - # - 1 &, 1], z]
```

What does `MinimalPolynomial[]` do behind us (in other words, what is the algorithm?)

Comment: :) ,Thanks.   that's that I want,Verbeia, and I also want to find out its implemention . maybe R.M is right , it's not approperate to post it here

Comment: @R.M Mma internals should be on topic. Perhaps not about general CAS algos.

Comment: @belisarius Oh, I agree that internals is on topic... we even have a tag: [tag:implementation-details] for it. I got the feeling the OP wanted to know how the CAS algo worked.

Answer (score 12):

It uses a resultant computation. The idea is this. We are given algebraic numbers $x$ and $y$, where $p(x)=0$ and $q(y)=0$ are the minimal polynomials. We want to find the defining polynomial for $z=x+y$. We use $p(x)=p(z-y)$ and $q(y)$, and eliminate $y$ using the classical method of resultants.

Here is how it would go for your example.

```
p[x_] := #^5 - # - 1 &[x]
q[y_] := #^7 - # - 1 &[y]

Resultant[p[z - y], q[y], y]

(* 53 + 116*z - 191*z^2 - 1393*z^3 + 7677*z^4 - 10429*z^5 + 20034*z^6 - 
   34395*z^7 + 36887*z^8 + 32235*z^9 + 11257*z^10 - 77061*z^11 - 
   51163*z^12 + 19040*z^13 + 46835*z^14 + 27874*z^15 + 13792*z^16 + 
   12785*z^17 + 29225*z^18 + 29750*z^19 + 12152*z^20 + 1820*z^21 + 
   85*z^22 + 2300*z^23 + 2030*z^24 + 448*z^25 - 42*z^26 - 21*z^27 + 
   5*z^28 + 5*z^29 + 7*z^30 + 7*z^31 - z^35 *)
```

Comment: Thank you, you are so brilliant!

Comment: @yoyowinwin Glad you like this method, but it wasn't me-- it really is classical.

Comment: Nice, `Resultant[5 - x + x^3 /. (x -> b/y), 8 - y + y^4, y]` also seems to work for the product although the first argument is not a polynomial in y. This method also allows reducing Root objects with parameters to reduce combinations of algebraic functions. I do not see why `RootReduce` and `MinimalPolynomial` do not implement this for roots with parameters, it's rather powerful being able to reduce algebraic functions in this way.

Comment: With the caveat that continuity is not guaranteed when reducing products and sums and so all roots need to be followed.

Answer (score 5):

[`Here`](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/Add-onsLinks/StandardPackages/NumberTheory/AlgebraicNumberFields.html) is a clue

> This package introduces functions for computation within finite algebraic extensions of rationals. For more information on the notions and algorithms used, see for instance H. Cohen, A Course In Computational Algebraic Number Theory, Springer-Verlag, 1993.